# Why doesn't "call" work in a Windows 7 batch file?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

I have a `.bat` file which contains

```
call "c:\my path\myprog.exe"
```

but the command prompt says that `call` isn't a command.

Comment: Please don't cross post the same question on different sites.

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Answer (score 6):

Call is not for running other programs like that, it is strictly for calling other batch files. You probably want `start` if your program starts another window, else just type the command by itself on one line.

e.g.

```
start calc.exe
"C:\Stuff\Program.exe"
```

Comment: Needs some empty quotes or a title though. eg. `start "" /b /i "C:\Stuff\Program.exe"` The `b` switch supresses a new window and the `i` switch passes the current variables.

Comment: While the documentation for `call` states that it is for running batch files it has no problems running any other command as well.

Answer (score 0):

"c:\my path\myprog.exe" 
without START or call to execute your myprog.exe . that's how it's done in windows 7